# Databound PivotControl jumps over pivots when they come from similar objects [WP7]

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding, pivot

I have a PivotControl with bindings. Everything worked well until I added a pivot two pivots with the same title, let's call them C and C', and A an B two different pivots, ordered like this: AC'BC. Now, when I try to go from B to C everything is OK. But when I go from A to C, it does strange things: doesn't move, moves the titles but not the content... weird.

I debugged the SelectionChanged event in the PivotControl, and it's even weirdest. It's called two times: the first, a transition from C to another pivot and then another call which contains the right transition, from A to C.

I've tried everything. The databinding is a list of structs, like this:

```
struct Resource
{
   public someenum Type;
   public string Data;
   public string Identifier { get {...} set {...} }
   public UserToken User;
}
```

The title of the pivot is set by a IValueConverter, which takes the string Identifier (which is a function of Type, Data and User) as the parameter. I changed it to make the titles always different, but it still does not work. For example, when Type and Data are the same there are error, although Identifier and User are different.

I have written both operators == and != for Resource, and also for UserToken. They behave as they should, but still does this weird transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer. After a lot of googling, I noticed that maybe GetHashCode had something to do in this mess. I modified the definition of getHashCode in the struct and, voilá! It works smoothly :)

Just a tip: to get a good GetHashCode function return a XOR of the volatile parameters of the function. In my case, the code was this:

```
Type.GetHashCode() ^ Data.GetHashCode() ^ User.GetHashCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Stating the obvious: give them different names.

If they are different you should give them different names. Just post-fix the name with a counter.

**EDIT**

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx):

> Name is one of the very few dependency properties that cannot be
>   animated (IsAnimationProhibited is true in metadata), because the name
>   itself is vital for targeting an animation. Data binding a Name is
>   technically possible, but is an extremely uncommon scenario because a
>   data-bound Name cannot serve the main intended purpose of the
>   property: to provide an identifier connection point for code-behind.

Comment: I already tried that, but it still does wierd things. I've updated the question with more code.

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to assign names using data binding. I added to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't talking about the Name porperty, but about the title of the pivot. I should have clarified that before.

Comment: Wow, that is something completely different! Still, my first answer remains as I consider it a bad user experience to repeat the same name. I have used DataBinding for the titles and it never gave me any issues. My titles were always distinct though.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have any issues before. But this is so strange... Even when the Converter gives always different names (the parameter is always different).

Comment: I don't have it near right now, but it simply took a string like "twitteruser;home" or "twitteruser;list:listname" and returned "home" and "listname" respectively.

Anyways,that wasn't the problem. It was the GetHashCode() function as I explain above.